# {caret}xgbTree model not running when weights included, runs fine without them

Tags: r, xgboost, r-caret

I have a dataset off which I have no problem building an xgbTree model without weights, but once I include weights -- even if the weights are just all 1 -- the model doesn't converge. I get the 
`Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:` error and when I print the warnings, I get `In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  ... :There were missing values in resampled performance measures.` as the last message.

[This is a drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SzoaNfFPZm6BxSAWVLnaa2IrrLBPI8xA) to the RData file containing the info -- it was too big to print, and smaller samples didn't always reproduce the error.

It contains 3 objects: `input_x`, `input_y`, and `wts` -- the last one is just a vector of 1s, but it should eventually it should be able to accept numbers on the interval (0,1), ideally. The code I used is shown below. Note the comment next to the weight argument that produces the error.

```
nrounds<-1000

tune_grid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(from = 200, to = nrounds, by = 50),
  eta = c(0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3),
  max_depth = c(2, 3, 4, 5),
  gamma = 0,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 1
)

tune_control <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 3, 
  verboseIter = FALSE, 
  allowParallel = TRUE 
)

xgb_tune <- caret::train(
    x = input_x,
    y = input_y,
    weights = wts, # If I remove this line, the code works fine. When included, even if just 1s, it throws an error.
    trControl = tune_control,
    tuneGrid = tune_grid,
    method = "xgbTree",
    verbose = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: see if solution below works for you.. I ran your code for a few nrounds and it was ok.. did not try over the whole range. Might also have to do with the parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 13.10.2021.** thanks to @waterpolo

The correct way to specify weights is via the `weights` argument to `caret::train`

```
xgb_tune <- caret::train(
    x = input_x,
    y = input_y,
    weights = wts,
    trControl = tune_control,
    tuneGrid = tune_grid,
    method = "xgbTree",
    verbose = TRUE
  )
```

see a more verbose answer here: [Non-tree model error when using xgbTree method with Caret and weights to target variable when applying the varImp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731960/non-tree-model-error-when-using-xgbtree-method-with-caret-and-weights-to-target)

**Old incorrect answer below:**

According to the [function source](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/xgbTree.R) weights argument is called `wts`.

Line:

```
if (!is.null(wts))
  xgboost::setinfo(x, 'weight', wts)
```

Running

```
xgb_tune <- caret::train(
    x = input_x,
    y = input_y,
    wts = wts,
    trControl = tune_control,
    tuneGrid = tune_grid,
    method = "xgbTree",
    verbose = TRUE
  )
```

should produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add @missuse response from another post ([Non-tree model error when using xgbTree method with Caret and weights to target variable when applying the varImp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731960/non-tree-model-error-when-using-xgbtree-method-with-caret-and-weights-to-target)). The correct argument is    `weights`    .

Code:

```
xgb_tune <- caret::train(x = input_x,
    y = input_y,
    weights = wts,
    trControl = tune_control,
    tuneGrid = tune_grid,
    method = "xgbTree",
    verbose = TRUE
  )
```

The other thing that I found was that I needed to use weights > 1 or I would receive the same error message as you. For example, if I used inverse weighting I would receive the same message as you. Hope this helps.

Thanks @missuse for the lovely response in the other thread!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29936764)

Comment: @waterpolo Thanks for correcting my answer. It was indeed wrong. However I tried running all weights < 1, some weights > 1 and some weights < 1, as well as all weights > 1 and did not receive any errors. It would be great if you could expand your answer with a reproducible example with an inbuilt data set.